# Error while installing Chalice

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I am working with https://github.com/awslabs/chalice for using AWS Lambda, and I faced the following issue while installing using

> pip install chalice

This is the error.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py”, line 215, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py”, line 342, in run
   prefix=options.prefix_path,
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py”, line 784, in install
   **kwargs
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py”, line 851, in install
   self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py”, line 1064, in move_wheel_files
   isolated=self.isolated,
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py”, line 345, in move_wheel_files
   clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py”, line 316, in clobber
   ensure_dir(destdir)
 File “/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py”, line 83, in ensure_dir
   os.makedirs(path)
 File “/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py”, line 157, in makedirs
   mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ‘/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/click’
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using sudo pip install...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `sudo pip install chalice`